# A compact non-discrete group for any norm cannot be countable

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, topological-groups

Let be $G$ a compact **non-discrete** group for some norm $N$, then $G$ is a Baire space.

Let us suppose that $G$ is countable.

Then:

$\begin{equation*}
G = \bigcup\limits_{x \in G} \{ x \}
\end{equation*}$

We have:

- $\{ x \}$ has no interior and is closed.
- $G$ is a countable reunion of closed sets with no interior.

By Baire theorem, $G$ has no interior.

But, as $G$ is closed and open by definition, $G$ must be its own interior.

We have a contradiction, then $G$ cannot be countable.

I am trying to show that a compact group for any norm cannot be countable, is this proof right? Can it be generalized further? Is there any useless hypothesis? Do I have the right to use the induced topology for $G$ where $G$ is something like $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{R})$?

Comment: Every group with discrete topology is a Hausdorff topological group. With this topology $\{x\}$ has an interior.

Comment: You may want to check degenerate cases. For instance, the discrete topology is of course Hausdorff. Then $\{x\}$ has interior $\{x\}$ since all sets in the discrete topology are clopen.

Edit: Ninja'd

Comment: Your argument doesn't work. If $G= \Bbb{Z}$ or $G=\Bbb{Z}_n$ (with the discrete topologies) then $G$ has isolated points and you can't apply the Baire category theorem.

Comment: @RobArthan I fixed the statement, now discrete topologies are excluded, is my argument valid?

Comment: You don't; seem to have made any relevant change.

Comment: @RobArthan If you take $G = \mathbb{Z}$, no matter which norm $N$ you take, for all $k \in \mathbb{Z}$, the interior of $\{ k \}$ is empty, right? If the argument still does not work, could you guide me to understand why?

Comment: Under the usual norm on $\Bbb{Z}$ the topology is the discrete topology and the interior of $\{k\}$ is $\{k\}$.

Comment: @RobArthan Okay, so I misunderstood the notion of discrete. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're right that a compact topological group cannot be countably infinite, because of Baire (which implies that a countable Baire (Hausdorff top.) group is discrete, as there must be an open singleton, which implies that all singletons are open, etc.)

A better proof:

> Suppose $X$ is be a countable Baire topological group (which includes $T_1$-ness). Then $X$ is discrete.

Then $X = \cup_{x \in X} \{x\}$. The Baire theorem tells us that one $\{x\}$ (which is closed) must have non-empty interior, so such an $x$ is an isolated point. But a topological group is homogeneous, so this means that *all* $x \in X$ are isolated points. So $X$ is a discrete space.

> Corollary: An infinite countable topological group cannot be compact.

In this context, compact implies Baire and an infinite discrete space is not compact.

The countably infinite is essential, as finite discrete groups are compact, and $S^1$ (any many others) is an uncountable compact group. In the first statement we cannot drop Baire, as the rationals are a non-discrete countable non-Baire group. And $\mathbb{Z}$ is the main (only?) example of a Baire countably  infinite topological group (locally compact implies Baire).

Comment: So my proof is not right? Can you point me out where my reasoning fails?

Comment: @Raito No, your proof is fine. I just point out it generalises to all Baire topological groups (where such a group is $T_1$ hence Tychonoff).

Comment: @RobArthan the idea of using Baire is OK, and the conclusion for the compact case (which he ends with) is correct.

Answer (score 2):

A compact topological group cannot be countable because it admits an [Haar measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haar_measure).

You have $1=\mu(G)=\sum_{g\in G} \mu(\{g\})$. It follows that the sum has to be finite (because $\mu$ gives the same measure on every singleton).

This is not true for non-compact groups (see my comment). For example $\mathbb{Z}$ with discrete topology is a topological Hausdorff group.

Comment: Is there any proof which do not reply on Haar measure?

Comment: @Raito: you need to provide a correct statement in order for us to help  you find a proof.